# Script to toggle IPV4 IP address, between the "obtain IP address automatically" settings, and a specific IP address and Subnet mask in windows cmd

Tags: command-line, ipv4

I am looking for a way to change the IPV4 IP address settings to a specific IP and Subnet mask, but also to change it to get the IP address automatically. I see plenty of resources for setting the IPV4 IP and DNS settings in windows cmd, but I don't see where i can change it to the "Obtain IP address automatically" setting.

Basically, I need to quickly switch my settings from the default IP wifi settings to a specific IP address and subnet mask (well, the default one, but it needs to be set when changing IPV4 settings), and back when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is used to obtain IP address automatically. When you'd want to revert the interface to using DHCP again, just run the following commands.

```
netsh interface ip set address name="<adapter-name>" dhcp
netsh interface ip set dns name="<adapter-name>" dhcp
ipconfig /release <adapter-name> && ipconfig /renew <adapter-name>
```